# Replace key-range in std::map with new entry

Tags: c++, stdmap

For a `std::map<K,V>`, is there a better way to replace all elements with keys in a certain range [first, last) with a single new element? The new element `(k', v')` will be placed in the same place as the one of element of the original range. As an example, if I have a map with elements 
`{ (0,'a'), (10, 'b'), (20, 'c'), (30,'d'), (40,'e')}`, I want to remove the elements  `{(10, 'b'), (20, 'c')}` and put a new element `(k', v')` in the map with `0 < k' < 30`.

The best I could come up with is

```
auto left = map.lower_bound(first);
auto right = map.upper_bound(last);
map.insert( map.erase(left, right), make_pair(k',v') );
```

This requires three `O(log n)` operations to search both keys and range-erase the elements. Insertion is amortized constant because of the hint. I know that combining the three operations is still O(log). I am wondering if there is some kind of trick which I can't see, e.g. to combine the search and the erase operation, but `std::map` doesn't have a `erase(firstKey, lastKey)` function.

Comment: You cannot theoretically go under O(log n), but you can do miracles when you have access to the underlying RB-tree of a large map...

Comment: Why range erase is O(log n) ?

Comment: @Slava The standard says so. For a map c, the complexity of c.erase(first, last) is log(c.size()) + std::distance(first, last)

Comment: @lorro I know that I cannot be faster than O(log n), but I wonder if there is a way to reduce the constant factor in O(log n), e.g. by combining some of the O(log n) steps into a single operation. To make things harder, I don't want to implement a new tree but stick with std::map.

Comment: @Jens so if I call `for( it = first; it != last;  ) it = map.erase( it );` that would be amortized constant, but if I call special method for that, it will make log n? Sounds suspicious

Comment: @Jens cpluplus.com says "For the last version (erase(first,last)), linear in the distance between first and last." so looks like typo in cppreference. Are you sure standard says so as well?

Comment: Created question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002619/stdmap-range-erase-complexity