# std::map range erase complexity

Tags: c++, time-complexity, stdmap

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) says that complexity of range erase of `std::map` is:

> log(c.size()) + std::distance(first, last)

while erase for single element by iterator is amortized constant. So if I erase elements in a loop:

```
for( auto it = first; it != last; it = map.erase( it ) );
```

that should be linear on `std::distance(first, last)`, and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/) agrees with that. What does standard say? Is this just typo on cppreference.com?

Comment: As far as I know map is based on red black trees in all implementation that I know. Just curious how did they get erase with amortized constant (with logarithmic rotations required for rb-tree).

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper no I am telling that if standard says so I would like to know why. Should I edit question specially for you?

Answer (score 15):

`log(c.size()) + std::distance(first, last)`

When (first,last) is the entire range, that is the bigger factor, so this simplifies to `std::distance(first, last)`, which is linear, so this is consistent with your thoughts.

`it = map.erase( it )` is *amortized* constant. It's constant, plus a tiny bit for traversal and balancing.  And when you add all those occasional tiny bits together over `n` iterations, they sum to something in `log(c.size())`. You still have to add these to the `n` constant-time erasures themselves, for a total of `log(c.size()) + std::distance(first, last)`.

In either case, what you want to use is `map.clear()`, which is `O(n)` with a very small constant. It's far faster than erasing one at a time, since it can skip the balancing.

Comment: Well explained. I thought the amortized constant could be the reason it's not linear but I couldn't come up with a calculation.

Comment: Can you point to a paper or source that shows that rb-tree removal has amortized constant runtime? Does not seem obvious to me. I mean I tried to come up with a rough token-method estimate, but I don't see how you manage to remain amortized constant for possibly indefinite size, which costs you a log(subtree_size) occasionally for a rebalance.

Comment: @midor: The C++ spec says that `std::map` must have amortized constant complexity removal. If rb-tree cannot do that, then map is not allowed to be implemented as an rb-tree.  I can't link to the spec directly, but various wikis agree. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase "Amortized constant"  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/ "amortized constant."  You're right that there must be a occasional rebalance, that's why it's specified as _amortized_ complexity, which allows this. Similarly, vector::push_back is amorized constant, even with reallocations.

Comment: I have read the spec, and both the sites, I have checked libstdc++'s implementation, which uses an rb-tree and calls a rebalance on erase, and I am currently checking the source for libc++, but I am quite sure all implementations will all use balanced trees, and very likely rb-trees. So there has to be a proof to show amortized constant time for that. Otherwise the standard would demand something impossible. The tree still has to have fixed log(n) insertion, because otherwise you would break the proven lower bound of n*log n for sort, but theortically you could have more efficient removal.

Comment: @midor: Did you check wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Operations  "the immediate result of an insertion or removal may violate the properties of a red–black tree. Restoring the red–black properties requires a small number (...amortized O(1)) of color changes (which are very quick in practice) and no more than three tree rotations (two for insertion)."  I don't have a paper, but given the fact everyone is using red-black trees, it seems a safe assumption that Wikipedia is right. The trick is that most sources talk about complexity rather than amortized complexity

Comment: http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/Toolbox/SortedSequences.pdf shows what I was looking for

Comment: You explain why in my loop amortized constant can add up to log(c.size()), questionable but ok. But issue is that  map method does not have to rebalance after each node erase, it can erase them all and only then do rebalance once. So still does not explain why this method has to have this complexity.

Comment: @Slava: Yes, you're right. It does erase them all and rebalance once. Which  is "a tiny bit for traversal and balancing. And when you add all those ocasional tiny bits togeather, they sum to C*log(c.size()) for some C>1."

Comment: i think `c.size()=n` ;so `C*log(c.size())=C*log(n)` is better than O(n),am i wrong?

Comment: Your math is right. For erasing a single element, the total is `O(log(n)+1) -> O(log(n))`. For erasing the entire tree, the total is `O(log(n)+n) -> O(n)`. The complexity depends on how much of the three you're erasing.

Answer (score 3):

I only have the draft, but they are consistent with the draft:

> a.erase(q1, q2)
>
> Erases all the elements in the range `[q1, q2)`...
>
> Complexity: **log(a.size()) + N** where N has the value `distance(q1, q2)`.

[n4594](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4594.pdf) Page 818.